# java program returns -1073741515 when is called from the project - ProcessBuilder

Tags: java

I have a java application which deals with executing some exe file. When I call this program from the command line or from another local Java application with the following code snippet:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test{
    public static void main (String args[]) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c",
          "Test.exe -export -f output.txt");
             
      File file = new File("C:\\_CommandOutput.txt");
      processBuilder.redirectOutput(file);
      processBuilder.redirectError(file);
      
       int exitVal = processBuilder.start().waitFor();
        System.out.println("Script executed and exit value is: "+ exitVal);
    }
}
```

everything is working and the application returns the exit code as zero.

But when I call the same program on the same PC with absolutely the same user account from some other Java JRE, I get an error return code -1073741515 from the application.

```
C:\>set PATH=C:\jdk1.8.0\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;

C:\>java -version
java version "1.8.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)

C:\>java Test
Script executed and exit value is: 0

C:\>set PATH=C:\Program Files\Utility\jre\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;

C:\>java -version
openjdk version "11.0.4" 2019-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.4+11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.4+11, mixed mode)

C:\>java Test
Script executed and exit value is: -1073741515
```

Comment: Does `Test.exe` set the exit code on exit properly and explicitly?

Comment: Not sure I have understood your question. But Test.exe is a 3rd party binary output of C/C++ code and all it does is export some data to the files.

Comment: Have you tried compiling your program with openjdk?

Comment: Yes I have tried compiling the program with openjdk and still see the error.
C:\>"c:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.5.10-hotspot\bin\javac.exe" Test.java
C:\>

Comment: Are you sure `Test.exe` runs fine and does what it is expected to do, but simply does not return a zero exit code under your Java 11 version? (It may just report it fails, so that's why exit codes are different.). Also, what does it do and what does it return if running for a batch script or the command prompt (I suppose `echo %errorlevel%` does it)? Another "also" is (I don't believe it is the issue, though): in `cmd`, should `"Test.exe -export -f output.txt"` be a single argument for `/c`?

Comment: Test.exe is working fine and it does its job. Exit code is not coming from the Test.exe but from the ProecessBuilder. Yes "Test.exe -export -f output.txt" is a single argument. 

Upon further investigation exit code -1073741515 means it is unable to find some dll file.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be no program called `Test.exe -export -f output.txt`. Try with this code instead, which looks for a program called `Test.exe` which takes several arguments:

```java
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c",
      "Test.exe", "-export", "-f", "output.txt");
```

Also, you should prefix `"Test.exe"` with its full path, say `"C:/Some/Path/Test.exe"`.